# I want to Implement Single sign-On in sas webReport 9.4

Tags: sas

I am new in sas.
I want to skip the Login window in SAS webReport9.4 for this I have already done this but did not able to skip the login window.
Thanks in Advance

```
metaport=XXXX
   metauser="sasad"
   metapass="Password@1"
   metarepository="Foundation";

   %let groupOrUserName=PUBLIC;
   %let identityType=IdentityGroup;
   %let webappName=SAS Web Report Studio;
   %let webappDescription=The SAS Web Report Studio web application;
   %let webappURI=http://<localhost>:8080/SASWebReportStudio/logonFromPortalWRS.do;
```